# Como apagar os dez primeiros registros de uma tabela quando chegar a um certo numero de rows?

Tags: php, sql, tabela-html

Boa noite, tenho uma tabela em SQL em que colocarei recomendações de filmes pelos usuários, mas eu quero que quando chegue a um total de registros nessa tabela, ela apague os registros mais antigos.

O meu código está assim:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO filmes_rec (filmes)
        VALUES ('$recomendacao')";

if($link->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo 'Obrigado por compartilhar seu gosto com a gente, você recomendou:<br>'; 
    echo '<p class="strong"><strong>';
    echo $recomendacao;
    echo '</strong></p>';
} else {
    echo "Error creating new record";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é possível colocar um valor máixmo de linhas na tabela, então é preciso criar um método para isso.

Você pode dar `COUNT` na tabela e, se o valor for maior do que o máximo, `DELETE` as mais antigas (utilizando ID, data ou o que permitir essa comparação).

```
$sql = INSERT INTO filmes_rec (filmes)
            VALUES ('$recomendacao');

if($link->query($sql) === TRUE) {

   $count = SELECT COUNT(*)
              FROM filmes_rec
             WHERE usuario_id = x //se você tiver um identificador que precisa usar no count

   if($link->query($count) > n) {
     DELETE FROM filmes_rec
           WHERE id > n;
   }

    echo 'Obrigado por compartilhar seu gosto com a gente, você recomendou:<br>'; 
    echo '<p class="strong"><strong>';
    echo $recomendacao;
    echo '</strong></p>';
} else {
    echo "Error creating new record";
}
```

Desse jeito eu uso o mesmo padrão que você está usando, mas é possível também fazer isso com uma `PROCEDURE`. Ao invés de rodar no script PHP vai rodar no MySQL e tem menos chances de dar problema por alteração de código ou coisas do tipo (o método estará vinculado ao DB).

Comment: Não foi especificado o SGBD mas outras soluções seriam TRIGGER ou uma procedure em agendamento (jog , event etc) , mas estas soluções dependem do BD.

Comment: Eu  não quero delimitar linhas no banco de dados, eu só quero fazer que quando chegar a um número especifico de linhas, ele apague alguns registros da tabela.

Comment: Não entendi. Você precisa que quando a tabela chegue a 51 linhas, ela apague o valor mais antigo para ficar apenas os 50 mais novos nao é?

Answer (score 2):

```
DELETE FROM filmes_rec ORDER BY nome_da_tabela ASC LIMIT 0, 10
```

em "nome da tabela" coloque o nome da tabela que que será usando de forma organizacional, por exemplo a coluna que contém a data dos registros assim ele apagará os 10 mas antigos.